# Unable to add template text to v-textarea with Vue and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have inherited an existing app written in Vue/Vuetify and it has an existing v-textarea element that I am trying to modify. The issue is that we now want to pre-populate this element with sample text that the user can edit to their needs.  I have tried adding `value` and `placeholder` properties to the v-textarea element and not gotten the sample text to show in the v-textarea.

Here is the dialog that contains the troublesome v-textarea:

```
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogAddComment" 
      hide-overlay 
      persistent 
      max-width="600px">
      <v-toolbar card color="blue-grey lighten-4" dense elevation="16"> 
        <v-toolbar-title color='black' class="body-2 ml-3">Add Comment</v-toolbar-title>         
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-icon @click.stop="closeDialogAddComment">close</v-icon>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
        <v-card>
          <v-flex>
            <v-layout column>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex mx-3>
                <v-select
                  :items="engagement.allIncidentTypes"
                  item-text="incidentCategoryText"  
                  item-value="incidentCategoryKey"              
                  label="Category"
                  :rules="[v => !!v || 'Category is required']"
                  required
                  v-model="incident.incidentCategoryKey"
                ></v-select>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex mx-3>
                <v-select
                  :items="zeroTo8"
                  label="Impact (Hours)"
                  :rules="[v => (v === 0 || v <9) || 'Impact is required']"
                  required
                  v-model="incident.numberOfHours"
                ></v-select>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex mx-3>
                <v-textarea
                  name="input-7-1"
                  label="Comment"
                  :rules="[v => !!v || 'Comment is required']"
                  required
                  v-model="incident.incidentFreeText"
                  counter=1024
                  maxLength=1024
                  rows=3
                  value='U Good lockers\nV Damaged lockers\nW Lockers replaced\nX (=U+V+W) Lockers installed\nY Lockers returned to warehouse'
                ></v-textarea>
                  <!-- -->
            </v-flex>
            </v-layout>          
          </v-flex>                  
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer/>
            <v-btn :disabled="!valid" color="primary" small @click="addIncident">Submit</v-btn>    
            <v-spacer/>         
          </v-card-actions>       
        </v-card>
      </v-form>
    </v-dialog>
```

I have tried setting the `placeholder` and `value` properties and seen nothing.  I initially tried setting a `text` property but then found the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textarea) on the vuetify.js site. They even have a [simple example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textarea#auto-grow) that does exactly what I want to do. But my implementation is not working. and I am stumpped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set both `v-model` and `value` at the same time.

One possible solution is removing v-model and update `incident.incidentFreeText` in @input event

```
<v-textarea
  name="input-7-1"
  label="Comment"
  :rules="[v => !!v || 'Comment is required']"
  required
  counter=1024
  maxLength=1024
  rows=3
  value='U Good lockers\nV Damaged lockers\nW Lockers replaced\nX (=U+V+W) Lockers installed\nY Lockers returned to warehouse'
  @input="onInput"
>
</v-textarea>

methods: {
  onInput(value) {
    this.incident.incidentFreeText = value
  }
}
```

Another possible solution is keeping v-model, remove `value`, but you need to set

```
this.incident.incidentFreeText='U Good lockers\nV Damaged lockers\nW Lockers replaced\nX (=U+V+W) Lockers installed\nY Lockers returned to warehouse'
```

somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you I will try both options

Comment: You put me on the right track... I ended up adding `v-on:change="onChange"` to my Vue element and then an `onChange` method that sets `this.incident.incidentFreeText`